# My SharePoint SQL server is Having Obsolete version?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My SQL Server of SharePoint 2013 environment is having an Obsolete version of SQL and if i upgrade the version of it will it affect us anyway to the server or data or functionality or configurations?

Please help me

Comment: what version of SQL u are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Schedule a Downtime for the SharePoint I will stop the IIS & timer
   services so that no connection should make to SQL server while
   patching.

   2. Apply the Patch to SQL server, test and verify it.
   3. Bring the SharePoint Server back online. Test it. Test this in the lower environments and then schedule it for production.
      1st.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 supports SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012, and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1+. You can certainly do an in-place upgrade, which I've had success with in the past on non-production systems.

You can also build out a new SQL Server running one of the above versions and move the databases to it. Follow this article to perform that process: [Move all databases in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx).